# Cordova BarcodeScanner continuous reading

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, meteor, qr-code

I'm using MeteorJs and Cordova with the Barcodescanner plugin.
I need to do multiple reads of different qrcodes, and send every read to a remote server.

With this code I can make one read and then Cordova closes the camera (for make a new one I need to recall the code).

```
cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
    function(result) {
        Meteor.call('newQR', result.text);
    },
    function(error) {
        alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
    }
);
```

How can I make mutiple and continuous readings (without exiting from the camera reader)?

Thanks.

Comment: It seems that this feature has not been implemented ( http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/can_you_use_the_barcode_scanner_plugin_in_continuous_scan_mode). Phonegap/Cordova plugin : https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner is just a fork of https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner.

The simplest way to achive that is to relaunch cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan after each success and/or fail. If you want more, you'll need to hard-code it yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
function scanBarcode() {
    cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
        function(result) {
            Meteor.call('newQR', result.text);
            if( !result.cancelled ) {
                scanBarcode();
            }
        },
        function(error) {
            alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
        }
    );
}
scanBarcode();
```

Comment: Work very well, thanks!

I've seen that works in this way as well.  `if (result.text.length === 0) return;`

Answer (score 0):

In my meteor project ,I have been struggling with a problem of putting cordova barcode scanner inside a fixed div inside a template. Since , you also using same cordova barcode scanner plugin for meteor , i wanted to check whether yo could help any bit regarding this . Problem details is available at following link

[MeteorJs putting Cordova barcode scanner inside a fixed div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30919104/meteorjs-putting-cordova-barcode-scanner-inside-a-fixed-div)